# How to delete .original file after Spring boot maven build

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven-2, spring-boot-maven-plugin

After built, we are getting two jars. 
One myjar.jar with all dependencies and another one myJar.jar.original without dependencies. How to delete the myJar.jar.original file ?

```
<build>
    <finalName>myJar</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it with maven-antrun-plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <delete file="target/myJar.jar.original" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the question apparently there are two possible ways you are getting myJar.jar.original.
1. There might be repackage configuration in your pom.xml which repackages a jar or war that is built during the package phase of the Maven lifecycle.

Here is sample pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- ... -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If the above configuration is present then you simple $ mvn package command will generate myJar.jar.original and myJar.jar

```
$ mvn package
$ ls target/*.jar
target/myJar.jar target/myJar.jar.original
```

Secondly you might be using maven repackage to build you mvn

```
$ mvn package spring-boot:repackage
$ ls target/*.jar
target/myproject-1.0.0.jar target/myproject-1.0.0.jar.original
```

So please check your maven configuration and if you have the repackage in your pom than please remove it. Else if you are building using "$ mvn package spring-boot:repackage" than i would suggest you "$ mvn package"